# fork exec and mmap issues

Tags: c++, linux, exec, fork, mmap

For the application I'm developing (under Linux, but I'm trying to maintain portability) I need to switch to shared memory for sharing data across different processes (and threads inside processes). There is a father process generating different children

I need for example to get every process able to increment a shared counter using a named semaphore.

In this case everything is ok:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

#define SEM_NAME "/mysem"
#define SM_NAME "tmp_sm.txt"

int main(){
    int fd, nloop, counter_reset;
    int *smo;
    sem_t *mutex;

    nloop = 100;
    counter_reset = 1000;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        /* child */
        /* create, initialize, and unlink semaphore */
        mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0777, 1);
        //sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
        /* open file, initialize to 0, map into memory */
        fd = open(SM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
        smo = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        close(fd);
        /* INCREMENT */
        for (int i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {
            sem_wait(mutex);
            cout << "child: " << (*smo)++ << endl;
            if(*smo>=counter_reset){
                (*smo)=0;
            }
            sem_post(mutex);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    /* parent */
    /* create, initialize, and unlink semaphore */
    mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0777, 1);
    sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
    /* open file, initialize to 0, map into memory */
    fd = open(SM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    smo = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close(fd);
    /* INCREMENT */
    for (int i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {
        sem_wait(mutex);
        cout << "parent: " << (*smo)++ << endl;
        if(*smo>=counter_reset){
            (*smo)=0;
        }
        sem_post(mutex);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

So far so good: both semaphore and shared counter are ok (same address in memory) and increment and reset work fine.

The program fails simply by moving child source code into a new source file invoked by exec. Shared memory and named semaphore addresses are different therefore increment fails.

Any suggestion? I used named semaphores and named shared memory (using a file) to try to get the same pointer values.

---

UPDATE:

as requested by Joachim Pileborg, this is the "server side" improvements respect above original code:

```
...
if (fork() == 0) {
    /* child */
    /*spawn child by execl*/
    char cmd[] = "/path_to_bin/client";
    execl(cmd, cmd, (char *)0);
    cerr << "error while istantiating new process" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
...
```

And this is the "client" source code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#define SEM_NAME "/mysem"
#define SM_NAME "tmp_ssm.txt"

int main(){
    int nloop, counter_reset;
    int *smo;
    sem_t *mutex;
    /* create, initialize, and unlink semaphore */
    mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0777, 1);
    //sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
    /* open file, initialize to 0, map into memory */
    int fd = open(SM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    smo = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close(fd);
    nloop=100;
    counter_reset=1000;
    /* INCREMENT */
    for (int i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {
        sem_wait(mutex);
        cout << "child: " << (*smo)++ << endl;
        if(*smo>=counter_reset){
            (*smo)=0;
        }
        sem_post(mutex);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

executing this code cause the process to block (deadlock) and waiting for an infinite time. looking at addresses they are tipically found to be:

```
father semaphore: 0x7f2fe1813000
child semahpore: 0x7f0c4c793000
father shared memory: 0x7f2fe1811000
child shared memory: 0x7ffd175cb000
```

removing 'sem_post' and 'sem_wait' everything is fine but I need mutual exlusion while incrementing...

Comment: You shouldn't look so hard at the actual addresses, these will be different because it's different processes. Also, you don't call `sem_unlink` in the parent process I hope? Also, since `mmap` returns -1, you should check the error code (`errno`, or print it out using `perror`).

Comment: Oh and by the way, you setting the wrong mode in the call to `shm_open`. It should be a file mode like in your call to `sem_open`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: no sem_unlink is no more called... I didn't modify original code for tracing changement but I'm gonna add comments now... I'm going to check everything you told me...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for your last hint! I checked and changed from 'shm_open' to 'open' and I don't get anymore a fail in child shared memory address. now the problem are the semaphore (without them everything works fine) which cause a deadlock. I'm editing first post code to be consistant...

Answer (score 2):

Don't unlink the semaphore. it actually removes the semaphore.

From the [`sem_unlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_unlink) manual page:

> **sem_unlink()** removes the named semaphore referred to by name. The semaphore name is removed immediately. The semaphore is destroyed once all other processes that have the semaphore open close it.

This means that once you've created the semaphore in the parent process, you immediately remove it. The child process then will not be able to find the semaphore, and instead creates a new one.

Comment: mmmm thanks... this is probably coming from previous version of the program in which semaphore and shared memory were created before fork. Fixing it!

Comment: @schu Instead of having your working program in the question, you should probably make your non-working programs in there, scaled down to the bare essentials.

Comment: its just for saving space since modifications are not so traumatic and I presume the error is somewhere in the way I allocate semaphore and shared memory... but an Update is coming...